# Unable to use libsvm with OCaml

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, libsvm, lapack

I tried to use libsvm in an OCaml project :

```
open Lacaml.D
open Libsvm
```

However, I am facing this strange bug when I try to run my makefile :

```
ocamlfind: Error from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch
```

My makefile being :

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -o prog -linkpkg -package lacaml -package libsvm Example1.ml
```

I made sure all the packages were present (using depext) :

```
# Installed packages for system:
base-bigarray             base  Bigarray library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-bytes                base  Bytes library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-ocamlbuild           base  OCamlbuild binary and libraries distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-threads              base  Threads library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-unix                 base  Unix library distributed with the OCaml compiler
[...]
lacaml                   8.1.1  OCaml-bindings to BLAS and LAPACK.
lbfgs                    0.8.8  Minimization of multidimensional functions on bounded or unbounded domains.
libsvm                   0.9.3  LIBSVM bindings for OCaml
```

Comment: did you try passing -thread to ocamlfind ? see http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.7.1/doc/guide-html/x265.html

Comment: It worked, if you can post it as an answer, I will validate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instruct ocamlfind to select the thread libs by gving it the option -thread or -vmthread - see   [ocamlfind](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.7.1/doc/guide-html/x265.html)